# How can I fix a "several files with the same basename" error when compiling a static library with node-gyp?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm learning how to create a NodeJS binding for a native library, using [nanomsg-next-generation (nng)](https://github.com/nanomsg/nng) as my target.

nng uses CMake/Ninja as a build system, so I figure I'll need to create a .gyp file to compile it as a static library that can be used by the native addon. I started doing so in here: https://github.com/jportela/node-nng/blob/master/deps/nng.gyp

I'm getting the following error when running `node-gyp rebuild`, because nng uses the same basename for different source files:

```
static library deps/nng.gyp:nng#target has several files with the same basename:
  ipc: nng/src/platform/posix/posix_pollq_epoll.c nng/src/supplemental/ipc/ipc.c nng/src/transport/ipc/ipc.c
  tcp: nng/src/supplemental/tcp/tcp.c nng/src/transport/tcp/tcp.c
  tls: nng/src/supplemental/tls/mbedtls/tls.c nng/src/supplemental/tls/none/tls.c nng/src/transport/tls/tls.c
  options: nng/src/core/options.c nng/src/supplemental/util/options.c
  websocket: nng/src/supplemental/websocket/websocket.c nng/src/transport/ws/websocket.c
  pair: nng/src/protocol/pair0/pair.c nng/src/protocol/pair1/pair.c
libtool on Mac cannot handle that. Use --no-duplicate-basename-check to disable this validation.
gyp: Duplicate basenames in sources section, see list above
```

From what I could see this error should be fine, but I don't know how to specify the `--no-duplicate-basename-check` flag (I've tried `node-gyp rebuild --no-duplicate-basename-check` without success).

So, I have two questions:

1. Is my approach here to convert nng to a static library correct? (I've thought of using the existing CMake/Ninja scripts, since they have a build command to create a static library, but I think it wouldn't integrate with the Native Node addon).
2. How can I bypass this duplicate basename check validation?

You can see the full example here: https://github.com/jportela/node-nng/

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?